# Sencha Touch: Clear Select Field's Value on an event

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have 2 select fields where, the second select field loads on the first select field's **change** event. That is, the second select field is dependent on the first select field's value.

Something like this.

```
listeners: {
     change: function(this, value){
        //Pass value parameter to the 2nd select field's store
     }
}
```

Though this works fine. I would like to clear the second select field's value when the first select field is selected i.e. dropped down.

I'm new to Sencha Touch, so I'm not sure if there are any events / methods available that I can use to get this thing working.

To be more clear - In Ext JS, we have a clearValue() method to clear the combo box's value. I'm looking for something similar with the Sencha Touch 1.1.

Any help towards the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just set the value to an empty string using `setValue("")`? I would assume this would trigger the emptyText property of the selectbox and also the change event (if there's anything listening for it)

Answer (score 0):

More info to make the answer more clear.

Here is what I did -

```
listeners:{
    change: function(combo, value){ 
          2ndSelectField_Store.load(
              params: {
                  query: value
              }
              callback: function(){
                   2ndSelectField.setValue(' ');
              }
          );
    }
}
```

Initially, I was using the setValue(' ') on the change event (which didn't work). Reason - The store still had the old data. So I had to refresh the store for the new value from select-field 1 and do setValue(' ') on the callback.